# Prove that $\sin\theta_1.\sin\theta_2.\sin\theta_3=\frac{r^2_1}{16R^2}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If $2\theta_1,2\theta_2,2\theta_3$ are the angles subtended by the circle escribed to the side $a$(opposite to vertex $A$) of a triangle at the centers of the inscribed triangle and the other two escribed circles,prove that $\sin\theta_1.\sin\theta_2.\sin\theta_3=\frac{r^2_1}{16R^2}$

Here $r_1$ is the radius of the circle escribed to the side $a$(opposite to vertex $A$) and $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle.

---

I dont know what is the relation satisfied by $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ and could not think more about it.Please help me in solving this question

Comment: Do you have a diagram of the problem?

Comment: @Paul,i dont have diagram for this.

Comment: Please try to provide a diagram. And state where your problem originated. Also clarify all the variables, $R$ in particular.

Comment: $r_1$ is the radius of escribed circle opposite side $a$ and $R$ is the circumradius.

Comment: Why downvote folks?Its a very good problem from S L Loney.

Comment: Just guessing on the downvoting:  No diagram.  No identification of initial figure (seems to be a triangle).  No clarification of labelling of initial figure.  No clarification in the question of quantities in the equation, e.g. $r_1$, $R$..  (Use the "edit" link to the left of the block of questioner data to finish describing the problem.)  No attempted solution nor research related to a solution.  But that's just a guess.  (I neither upvoted nor downvoted.)

Comment: @Brahmagupta , Use geogebra.

Comment: You should review your identity. The LHS is symmetric (with respect to A, B, C) while the RHS is not.

Comment: @Brahmagupta Is the source of your question the `Plane Trigonometry' by S. L. Loney (first published 1893)? Is it question 6 on p245 of exercise set 37 (XXXVII) which starts on p244? If so, I think you misunderstood the question and phrased it incorrectly. I apologize if I guessed the source wrong. Please could you specify the origin of your question?

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to reverse engineer the solution to the question.

The [Law of the sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) states that:

$$\frac{a}{\sin{\alpha}}=\frac{b}{\sin{\beta}}=\frac{c}{\sin{\gamma}}=2R$$

Thus, In a triangle:
$$\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{a}=\frac{\sin{\beta}}{b}=\frac{\sin{\gamma}}{c}=\frac{1}{2R}$$

In your case,  I **assume** we are talking about a [Quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) with sides of size $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ and with angles $\theta_1$,$\theta_2$,$\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$.

And thus:
$$\frac{\sin{\theta_1}}{a}\frac{\sin{\theta_2}}{b}\frac{\sin{\theta_3}}{c}\frac{\sin{\theta_4}}{d}=\frac{1}{16R^4}$$

$$\sin{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_2}\sin{\theta_3}=\frac{abcd}{\sin{\theta_4}16R^4}$$
And all we have left to understand / explain, is why
$$\frac{abcd}{\sin{\theta_4}}=r_1^2$$

**Again, a diagram would help**